# Features Extraction in retinal images

Tags: matlab

Please i need anyone's assistance on how to extract crossover points and bifurcation points from retina blood vessels using MATLAB. I intend to use different colours to distinguish the crossover points and bifurcation points.

I will appreciate your prompt response. Thanks

Comment: We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What have you tried so far that did not work?

Comment: this is John BG. Let's start with the definition of retinal cross over and retinal bifurcation, shall we? In the literature reference that you have mentioned http://webvision.med.utah.edu/2011/10/retinal-fundus-images-ground-truth-of-vascular-bifurcations-and-crossovers/ how can one discern between bifurcation and cross-over? my guess is that all vessels attached to same bifurcation have similar cross-section whereas cross-overs show some of the vessels, one or more with significantly smaller diameter. Please confirm that, should it be the other way around, or should bifurcations / crossovers